# Issue regarding letter spacing in canvas with text that has shadows

Tags: javascript, canvas, line, spacing, kerning

Since the canvas element does not support letter spacing when rendering text, I decided to add the unicode hair space character (code 8202) between letters of a text string for spacing. Unfortunately, different browsers display this character at different widths from one another, making it an unacceptable solution for my purpose.

An alternate solution I thought of using was to fill each character individually with an x offset that is defined by the spacing. The problem with this is when applying a shadow, the shadows that overlap will be darker than text that was filled all at once.

So it seems that both of these solutions won't work for me, but what are the alternatives?

Comment: I don't get it, what advantages would you get using an hair space for a lineheight problem ? Or did you meant letter-spacing ? In that case, you can compute each characters width with ctx.measureText. And remember to use the same webfont for every users.

Comment: I did mean letter spacing! Just updated, sorry. I keep calling it line spacing..